The character received by the HC05 is not what was expected
I'm trying to connect the HC05 device to my Arduino. I can connect to my Android device without a problem, and every time I send a character, the information is sent, but I can't process it in the code.
If I print the values ​​I receive, I get the symbol in the screenshot.
I have tried changing the device, changing the pins to which I connect the device, parsing the received character...
I attach the code. Just getting it to print the character it receives (I have tried sending numbers and letters) and then being able to process it later is enough for me.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   // Incluimos la librería  SoftwareSerial  
SoftwareSerial BT(10,11);    // Definimos los pines RX y TX del Arduino conectados al Bluetooth
char c;

void setup()
{
  BT.begin(9600);       // Inicializamos el puerto serie BT (Para Modo AT 2)
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Inicializamos  el puerto serie  
}

void loop()
{
  if(BT.available())    // Si llega un dato por el puerto BT se envía al monitor serial
  {
    Serial.println("BT available");
    Serial.println("Serial Write:");
    Serial.println("BT: " +BT.read());
    c = (char)BT.read();
    Serial.println("Print char:");
    Serial.println(c);

    if(c == '1'){
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        delay(1000); // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)

    } else if (c == '0'){
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        delay(1000); // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
    }
  }

}

Serial Monitor output:
09:07:42.081 -> BT available
09:07:42.115 -> Serial Write:
09:07:42.115 -> 
09:07:42.115 -> Print char:
09:07:42.155 -> �


remove the line Serial.println("BT: " +BT.read());

Have you modified your code according to the first comment?

Please print the received character in HEX, for example like this: Serial.println(c, HEX);. Then [edit] your question to show your findings, and add what character you expect to receive.
